# How can I use jq to get the key value pairs only and set as environment variable?

Tags: arrays, json, powershell, jq, hashicorp-vault

Below is the vault output generated by the vault command

vault kv get kv/Env | jq

```
{
  "request_id": "8498e5e4-050a-51e9-deaf-64a06a0",
  "lease_id": "",
  "lease_duration": 0,
  "renewable": false,
  "data": {
    "data": {
      "test": "test123",
      "test1": "test1234"
    },
    "metadata": {
      "created_time": "2022-11-17T12:2214.93229792Z",
      "custom_metadata": null,
      "deletion_time": "",
      "destroyed": false,
      "version": 1
    }
  },
  "warnings": null
}
```

I am unable to find a way to get only test and test1 and set as environmental variable in powershell. The issue is I would like to extract only test and test1, but it is under data/data which is like sublist and unable to find a way to extract it. Kindly help

I had provided the paths to delete as below but not sure if its efficient way to loop through

```
vault kv get kv/Env | jq 'del(.data.metadata, .request_id, .lease_id, .lease_duration, .renewable, .warnings)'
```

I would like to get the output something like below which I can loop through and set as variable.

```
test=test123
test1=test1234
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can acess the nested object with `.data.data`. You can convert an object into a list of key-value pairs with `to_entries`. Then it is only a matter of joining:

```
vault ... | jq -r '.data.data | to_entries[] | join("=")'
```

Output:

```
test=test123
test1=test1234
```

Comment: Note in powershell you have to backslash the doublequotes.  `join(\"=\")`

Answer (score 3):

To provide an **all-PowerShell alternative** to [knittl's helpful `jq` answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74499601/45375), which also addresses the aspect of setting environment variables:

```bash
(vault kv get kv/Env | ConvertFrom-Json).data.data.psobject.Properties |
  % { Set-Item Env:$($_.Name) $_.Value }
```

- [`ConvertFrom-Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-json) parses the input JSON into an object graph (based on type `[pscustomobject]`), so that regular OO dot notation can be used to drill down into the graph, such as with `.data.data` in this case.
- The `.Properties` collection of the [intrinsic `psobject` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Intrinsic_Members#psobject) is then used to reflect on the properties of the object contained in `.data.data`
- `%` (a built-in alias of the [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object) cmdlet) then processes each property and uses [`Set-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-item) with the [`Env:` drive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Environment_Variables) (representing all in-process environment variables) to set an environment variable for each property's name and value.